# Resetting position and size of SKSpriteNodes with *every* rotation?

Tags: uidevice

Do I really have to reset position and size of SKSpriteNodes with ***every*** rotation between landscape and portrait layout??

I've done that and it works .. **but** this seems to be **overkill** that the writers of Xcode internally compensated for .. vs. having the individual programmer having to do it.

I have a `getGameParms()` which resets positions based on:

```
#if os(iOS) && !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

    func getGameParms() {
       
        let roomRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        roomWidth    = roomRect.width * roomScale
        roomHeight   = roomRect.height * roomScale
        
        if (thisSceneName == "GameScene")
        {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {

                // changes here

            }
            else {

                // changes

            }
            
        }   // if (thisSceneName == "GameScene")
        
    }   // getGameParms
    
#elseif os(tvOS)
    
    func getGameParms() {
        
        let roomRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        roomWidth    = roomRect.width * roomScale
        roomHeight   = roomRect.height * roomScale
        
        if (thisSceneName == "GameScene")
        {

            // other changes here

        }

    }   // getGameParms
    
#endif
```

Again, the burdensome changes are done .. but are they really necessary?

As an alternative, I have called `getGameParms()` **just once** within my `viewDidLoad()` and the results are not correct.

For example, I place one `SKSpriteNode` at the very bottom of the `UIScreen` and it does **not** stay there with `UIDevice` rotation. I also size it horizontally such that it expands to the full width of the `UIScreen`. Rotation destroys that. if `getGameParms()` is called only once as just described.

Some explanation as to why would be appreciated.